# Como aplicar html em texto encontrado no javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando fazer o uso de regex no javascript

A situação é a seguinte: preciso pegar o texto que está contigo dentro do elemento com a classe texto.

Após pegar esse texto, devo analisar no mesmo se ele contém determinadas palavras ou expressões quaisquer. Segue uma lista do que preciso capturar:

- Qualquer palavra entre aspas duplas
- Qualquer palavra entre aspas simples
- Qualquer palavra que esteja dentro do array definido no javascript

Caso qualquer desses casos seja encontrado no texto, ele deve aplicar um elemento html **somente ao redor desses termos encontrados**. Segue o exemplo:

```
"Esse texto está entre aspas". Esse aqui não está. Não esqueça de colocar cláusula WHERE no seu UPDATE
```

Como deve ficar:

```
<span>"Esse texto está entre aspas"</span>. Esse aqui não está. Não esqueça de colocar cláusula WHERE no seu <span>UPDATE</span>
```

O que não consigo fazer, é pegar esses 3 itens e aplicá-los num replace de maneira simultânea nesse meu texto. Identifiquei no código abaixo, as expressões regulares e o array de palavras que preciso tratar. Porém não consigo dar o replace pegando o valor encontrado.

```
$(".texto").each(function(){
    var termos = ["insert", "update", "delete"];
    var texto = $(this).text(); 
    var aspasDuplas = "(\"(.*?)\"){1,}";    
    var aspasSimples = "(\'(.*?)\'){1,}";   
    // Fazer o replace  
})
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código vai te ajudar:

```js
var reservado = ['insert', 'update'];
var regex = new RegExp("([\"'][^\"']+[\"']|" + reservado.join('|') + ")", 'gi');

$('.texto').each(function(i, el) {
   
  var texto = $(el).html();
  
  var resultado = texto.replace(regex, '<span>$1</span>');
  
  $('#resultado1').text(resultado);
  $('#resultado2').html(resultado);

});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="texto">
  "Esse texto está entre aspas". Esse aqui não está. Não esqueça de colocar cláusula WHERE no seu UPDATE 
</div>

<br>

<strong>Resultado TEXTO:</strong>

<p id="resultado1"></p>

<strong>Resultado HTML (tag span com cor vermelha):</strong>

<p id="resultado2"></p>
```

**Explicação**

Primeiro eu faço um seletor para pegar todos os elementos com a classe texto (.texto), depois eu faço um loop com cada elemento, pego o valor do elemento da vez e faz uma substituição de acordo com o regex*, depois coloca o resultado na `div#resultado`.

**Regex***

```
"([\"'][^\"']+[\"']|" + reservado.join('|') + ")"
```

O `regex` funciona da seguinte forma:

[\"'] - Detecta aspas e aspas simples (note que o contra-barra é para escapar, já que iniciei a string com aspas duplas).

[^\"']+ - Detecta qualquer coisa que não seja aspas duplas e aspas simples uma ou mais vezes (no caso o texto que estará entre as aspas).

| - Tem o valor lógico OU (OR), nesse caso tá me servindo para especificar tudo que eu quero detectar de acordo com a sua regra (tudo entre aspas duplas e simples, e palavras reservadas).

reservado.join('|') - Ele vai pegar o array reservado e juntar os elementos em uma string separando por |, isso vai ajudar a gente a terminar o `regex`, com as palavras reservadas.

Os parênteses do inicio até o final servem para podermos usar esse valor na variável $1.

O 'gi', no segundo parâmetro representam:

g - corresponder globalmente

i - ignorar maiúsc./minúsc.

Mais informações: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Muito bom cara. Simples e fácil de entender! :)

Comment: Excelente JuniorNunes! Muito bom mesmo! A explicação está ótima também!